# Using flask-rq with flask-sqlalchemy occasionally raise ResourceClosedError

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

Recently, I have used flask-rq with flask-sqlalchemy to do some async-task with Model operations. While it occasionally raised the `ResourceClosedError` Error when calling Model methods. I don't know what happen to my rq-worker to cause the issue. I could not reproduce the issue correctly. Here is snippets.

**worker.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        QUEUE = get_queue()
        worker = get_worker()
        worker.push_exc_handler(retry_handler)
        worker.work()
```

**tasks.py** (which contains some async-tasks)

```
@job
def async_restart_task(task_id):
    creating_info = {"status": TaskStatus.Creating}
    task = TaskModel.update_task(task_id, creating_info)

    task = TaskModel.get_task_by_id(task_id)
    service = get_service(task.service)

    for jobs in iter_group(10, service.gen_jobs(task)):
        JobModel.add_jobs(jobs)
```

The async task occasionally raise the `ResourceClosedError`

`ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

I have no idea how to fix the issue by following a good practice. I have searched for a long while and got some same issue. ref: [Celery and SQLAlchemy - This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317344/celery-and-sqlalchemy-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-clo)

Is there any good suggestions or examples for those cases by using sqlalchemy in a async-task?

Answer (score 0):

I got a good summary and suggestions which came from [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317344/celery-and-sqlalchemy-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-clo) on using sqlalchemy in the `multi-processes` use-case likes my codes using flask-rq. Thanks to @zzzeek who is the author of sqlalchemy gave me a good explanation on the problem.

It tells us that when using sqlalchemy by sharing connection between multi-processes or workers would easily occur this class issue. We'd better to instantiate a new `engine` to do the job on the other process such as a forked child process.

So when using async queue like `celery` or `RQ` and any other queues with the sqlalchemy. It's better to inherit from the Original `Job` or `Task` Class to setup a new `engine` or `session` to fixed this issue. From this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460365/connection-is-closed-when-a-sqlalchemy-event-triggers-a-celery-task)

Finally. You could follow some advices or notes from @zzzeek refer to the [sqlalchemy FAQ](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#commands-out-of-sync-you-can-t-run-this-command-now-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-closed-automatically)